# FatFree sql based sessions

Tags: session, fat-free-framework

In my `beforeroute()` I have

```
new \DB\SQL\Session ($this->db) ;
$this->f3->set('SESSION.userid', 123);
```

However afterwards I don't see any record inserted into my sessions table.

Other than that, I had to manually create sessions table, as F3 wasn't able to, although sqlite.db file was writable by server group.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if `$this->db->exec` is working properly? That will give a hint if the issue is with sqlite or with session.

Comment: You were right, that failed too, as it was a problem with a permissions ,but not on a database itself but the directory where it was put in, because SQLITE makes some lock files in that directory, which then again has to be writeable by server. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.